# How to connect External Linux HDD to Virtualbox VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, external-hard-drive

I have an external StarTech USB HDD docking station plugged into my Windows 10 laptop. I am trying to configure Virtualbox to recognise the external HDD inside a VM.

Because the HDD has a Linux filesystem it does not map to a drive letter in Windows so I can't map it as an external Storage device in the VM settings. For example, if I open the storage settings of the VM, all of the controllers require you to select a drive letter from Windows but of course there is no driver letter assigned to the HDD.

It also doesn't seem to be recognised in the USB filter settings of the VM either.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Did you try [raw disk access](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)?  See this question : [how to create VMDK file in Virtualbox for adding USB as a new OS?](https://superuser.com/a/364405/269373)

Comment: If it is connected via USB you can simply redirect the USB device to the Linux guest. If the USB device is connected to a USB3 port you need to install the VirtualBox Extension Pack on the host system.

Comment: You might try a third-party program, e.g. Ext2Fsd, http://www.ext2fsd.com/, which lets you ad ext*n* filesystems as a drive letter. BTW, it's not a "Linux filesystem", but ext3, ext4, etc. Be specific, because not all apps work for all filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Raw disk access in Virtualbox using the suggested link resolved my issues but I did have to declare the disk "offline" using diskpart first and also had to run all cmd shells as administrator as well as run Virtualbox as administrator otherwise I got access denied errors.